# multiple value (or) in php variable is possible?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, codeigniter

is possible multiple value in php variable with condition (or). such as like this

```
$shippingCost = $selectedShipping['cost'] || null;
```

I've tried but it gives return error

[image: result]

Comment: try `$shippingCost = $selectedShipping['cost'] ?? null;`

Comment: You should check if both **variable** and **index** exists. `$shippingCost = isset($selectedShipping['cost']) ? $selectedShipping['cost'] : null`

Comment: It would tremendously help us to have a look how does `$selectedSihipping` looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use ternary operators to assign values to parameter when there are conditions to check. otherwise you can simply use if else conditions as well

```
using ternary operator 

$shippingCost = isset($selectedShipping['cost']) ? $selectedShipping['cost'] : null
```

```
using if,else

$shippingCost = 0;
if(isset($selectedShipping['cost'])){
  $shippingCost = $selectedShipping['cost'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I recall correctly, ternary operator (?:) tries to find if the value is truthy or falsy, so if it is not set, it will return an error or a warning.

What you are looking for, is passing a value depending on if its set or not.

Back in old times we've had `isset($array['key'])` or `array_key_exists` for the senior guys, however right now what you can do is use a null coalescing operator - ??.

`$array['key'] ?? null` - this will return whatever is under that key in the array, or null if its undefined.